# Set slider value

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, slider

i try to set a value to a slider after a button click,
but it does not work - the slider does not move. the code runs fine without mistakes.

It should be pretty simple but I can't figure it out.
xCode Version 4.5.2

Thanks!

---

here my code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *debugLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ButtonChangeValue:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize slider;

...

- (IBAction)slider:(UISlider *)sender {
    float value = [sender value];
    self.debugLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value: %f",value];
}

- (IBAction)ButtonChangeValue:(id)sender {
    slider.value = 90;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `minimumValue` and `maximumValue` to proper values first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem is that the slider accepts values between 0.0 and 1.0 (default values, change them with `_slider.maximumValue` and `_slider.minimumValue`). Try setting the value to 0.9 instead of setting 90 (if you mean 90%).

If the slider updates but is not animated, use :

```
[_slider setValue:0.9 animated:YES];
```

Note that given your code, you may need to use `self.slider` instead of `_slider`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I had to set the min- and maximum value directly in the code, i set it in attribute inspector and somehow that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
    self.slider.value = 90;
```

instead of

```
    slider.value = 90;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check My** [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356528/how-to-change-a-uislider-value-using-a-single-touch/14356751#14356751)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTapped:)];
    [slider addGestureRecognizer:gr];

}

 - (void)sliderTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)g 
    {

        UISlider* s = (UISlider*)g.view;
        if (s.highlighted)
            return; // tap on thumb, let slider deal with it
        CGPoint pt = [g locationInView: s];
        CGFloat percentage = pt.x / s.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat delta = percentage * (s.maximumValue - s.minimumValue);
        CGFloat value = s.minimumValue + delta;
        [s setValue:value animated:YES];

        NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",[self.slider value]];
        self.lbl.text=str;
    }
```

Comment: I did not down vote but OP wants to set the slider value on button click not on tap event.

Answer (score 1):

To use `slider.value = 90;`

Your ViewController.h should be:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
     UISlider *slider;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *debugLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ButtonChangeValue:(id)sender;

@end
```

And don't forget `@synthesize slider;` in your ViewController.m as well.

Otherwise, use `self.slider.value = 90;` or `_slider.value = 90;`

Answer (score 1):

For Swift, you can use:

```
slider.setValue(5.0, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using interface builder first thing to look at would be: are the UI components (slider, button) connected to the IBOutlets in File's owner. This is the most common source of problems like this.

Then check the min and max of the slider (default is 0;1 - as rdurand mentioned).

And spider1983 is correct also: since slider is a property, you can address it as self.slider (or _slider, but you shouldn't use the last one in this case).

Answer (score 0):

i think . as you have not mentioned maximum and minimum value of slider ,it is taking default max and min values that are 0 to 1. So it is not possible to set value =90. First change its max and min like this :

```
Slider.minimumValue = 1;
Slider.maximumValue = 100;
```

now try your thing ,

```
Slider.value =90;
```

Answer (score 0):

Within view

```
@State private var value1: Double = 0.9
```

Then make reference

```
Slider(value: $value1)
```