# Go to tapped position of UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UISlider` and I am trying to make the position go when the user taps to a certain time, instead of moving the thumb.

I tried to work it through [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717167/how-to-enable-tap-and-slide-in-a-uislider) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22718266/4705339) and I came to this approach. This is what I tried:

```
var slider: UISlider! // and maxValue, etc added in viewDidLoad

func sliderTapped(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    var pointTapped: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)

    var positionOfSlider: CGPoint = slider.frame.origin
    var widthOfSlider: CGFloat = slider.frame.size.width
    var newValue = ((pointTapped.x - positionOfSlider.x) * CGFloat(slider.maximumValue) / widthOfSlider)

    slider.setValue(Float(newValue), animated: true)

}
```

But, it is not letting me anywhere on slider and get the tapped value. It only lets me hold the thumb and slide it, but not tapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UISlider`'s method is `func setValue(_ value: Float, animated animated: Bool)`.

You'll need to cast your CGFloat to a Float.

So `durationSlider.setValue(Float(newValue), animated: true)`

Comment: It removed the error but doesn't change the slider's value on tapping. It only moves the slider if I hold the thumb and slide. Do you have any idea? Edit: Just updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is legit.  If you check the operands for `setValue` you'll see several possible calling sequences.  The one you probably want expects a `Float` (as opposed to a `CGFloat`) - but also requires an `animation:` boolean flag.

Try something like:

```
let floatNewValue = Float(newValue)
durationSlider.setValue(floatNewValue,animated: true)
```

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem. I have updated the question just now. It's not helping me achieve what I want to achieve