# How to delay start touch event of a UISlider in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

In my application, there is a **UISlider** which is only slidable after a long-press (let's say, after 0.1 seconds of the press). To prevent from the slider to interact immediately, I set `mySlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` as default. However, since `.isUserInteractionEnabled` will disable all the functions, including the long-press gesture, I use another transparent `UIButton` of the same size as the slider on the top of it to detect long-presses, and set `mySlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` in the callback action. This works fine, except that the `UIButton` must be released first and then the user tap the slider again to slide it instead of drag the slider directly within the same touch. This make the slider very inconvenient to use. Therefore, I would like to know if either:

1. There is a better way other than mine to make **UISlider** start sliding only after certain delay? I'm quite surprised that I couldn't find any solution on this. I thought this would be a common need for a slider to be locked at a certain point.

or

2. Following my solution, is there any way that I could start dragging the slider thumb within the same touch?

Thanks a lot for any kind of answer.

**Added:** My solution looks like the following: in the `TableViewCell`, there is a label, a slider, and an invisible button with the same size as the slider (The grey background area). I set slider attribute `isUserInteractionEnabled == false`, and then add gesture recogniser to manipulate the slider (such as single tap, double tap for my custom functions, and long-press gesture which enable the slider). After the button is long-pressed, the `isUserInteractionEnabled` of the slider will set to true until the thumb goes to the new value.

Basically I only want to disable the slider to respond too quickly for short taps, the other features of the slider would remain the same. I suppose there may be better ways to achieve this, the so far using an transparent button is the only way I could think of.

[image]

Comment: If you'll provide a demo to test then it'll be helpful to solve your problem

Comment: @VarunNaharia I've added some information about how I fulfilled my need so far. This works, but since there is a button in the front, after setting the slider user interactiveness to be enabled, I must release the button and then press again to drag, which is not intuitive at all. What I want is a normal slider except that it only start dragging after a certain delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable user interaction on slider and then add a gesture recogniser over it (Not exactly sure about user interaction though). Maybe do something like this

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self.slider, action: Selector("longPressAndSlide:"))
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0
self.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

In `longPressAndSlide` you can calculate the direction and delta of movement and set the value of slider accordingly.

This has been answer multiple times actually. just a better search would help you more.

**Update**
Check answers under - [How to enable "tap and slide" in a UISlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717167/how-to-enable-tap-and-slide-in-a-uislider)

**Latest Update**
As the comments suggest, we can add a button on top of the slider and add longPress gesture over it. The handling can be done in the handler Action for the gesture.

Comment: Hey thanks for the amazing answer. Finally I still put the `longPress` in my invisible button and disable the slider all the way since the slider longPress will not detected once its user interaction is disabled.