# iOS -How to have a separate UIView take control of a UISlider's thumbRect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uislider

I have a button that I press and a custom alert appears with a **normal** UISlider inside of it. There are some other views and labels that I have that show the distance etc that are above and behind the slider. What happens is the thumbRect of the slider doesn't slide to well when touched. I have to be very accurate when trying to slide it and it seems buggy. What I want to do is add a clear UIView in front of it (and the other views and labels above it) and have the clear UIView take control of the slider using a `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Here's the setup so far. The clearView is what I want to use to take control of the slider. Right now it's behind everything and **I colored the clearView red just so it's visible for the example**

[image]

```
bgView.addSubview(slider) // slider added to bgView
let trackRect = slider.trackRect(forBounds: slider.frame)
let thumbRect = slider.thumbRect(forBounds: slider.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: slider.value)
milesLabel.center = CGPoint(x: thumbRect.midX, y: slider.frame.origin.y - 55)
bg.addSubview(milesLabel) // milesLabel added to bgView

// ** all the other views you see are added to the bgView and aligned with the thumbRect's center **

let milesLabelRect = bgView.convert(milesLabel.frame, to: self.view)
let sliderRect = bgView.convert(slider.frame, to: self.view)

let topOfMilesLabel = milesLabelRect.origin.y
let bottomOfSlider = sliderRect.maxY
let distance = bottomOfSlider - topOfMilesLabel

clearView.frame = CGRect(x: milesLabel.frame.minX, y: milesLabel.frame.minY, width: milesLabel.frame.width, height: distance)
bgView.addSubview(clearView) // clearView added to bgView
bgView.insertSubview(clearView, at: 0)
```

When I slide the slider everything successfully slides with it including the clearView but of course the `thumbRect` is still in control of everything.

[image]

```
@objc func onSliderValChanged(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {

    slider.value = round(sender.value)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.slider.layoutIfNeeded()

        let trackRect = sender.trackRect(forBounds: sender.frame)
        let thumbRect = sender.thumbRect(forBounds: sender.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: sender.value)
        self.milesLabel.center = CGPoint(x: thumbRect.midX, y: sender.frame.origin.y - 55)

        // ** all the other views are aligned with the thumbRect's center as it slides **

        self.clearView.frame.origin = self.milesLabel.frame.origin
    })
}
```

The idea is to move the clearView to the front of everything and use that to control the thumbRect (don't forget it's only red for the example).

```
bgView.bringSubviewToFront(clearView)
// clearView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

[image]

I tried to use a `UIPanGesture` and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to have the clearView take control of the slider but when I slide the slider only the thumbRect slides, the clearView stays still. Look where the clearView (which is red) is and look where the `thumbRect` is after I slid it to the 10 mile point.

[image]

```
// separately tried a UILongPressGestureRecognizer too
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
clearView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
clearView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

@objc func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if slider.isHighlighted { return }

    let point = sender.location(in: slider)
    let percentage = Float(point.x / slider.frame.width)
    let delta = percentage * (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue)
    let value = slider.minimumValue + delta
    slider.setValue(value, animated: true)
}
```

If I play around with it enough the clearView sometimes slides with the the thumbRect but they definitely aren't in alignment and it's very buggy. I also lost control of all the other views the were aligned with the thumbRect.

**How can I pass control from the slider's thumbRect to the clearView?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the key to the problem here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505038/4833705). @PaulaHasstenteufel said

```
// also remember to call valueChanged if there's any
// custom behaviour going on there and pass the slider
// variable as the parameter, as indicated below
self.sliderValueChanged(slider)
```

What I had to do was

1. Use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`
2. comment out the UISlider's target action
3. use the code from the target action's selector method in step-4 instead of using it in `@objc func onSliderValChanged(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent { }`
4. take the code from step-3 and add it to a new function
5. add the function from step-5 to the bottom of the `UIPanGetstureRecognizer`'s method

1- use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and make userInteraction is enabled for the UIView

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
clearView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
clearView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

2- the Slider, I commented out it's addTarget for the `.valueChanged` event

```
let slider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    slider.minimumValue = 1
    slider.maximumValue = 5
    slider.value = 1
    slider.isContinuous = true
    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)

    // ** COMMENT THIS OUT **
    //slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSliderValChanged(sender:event:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return slider
}()
```

3- Take the code from the selector method the targetAction from above was using and instead insert that code in step 4

```
@objc func onSliderValChanged(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {

    /*
    use this code in step-4 instead

    slider.value = round(sender.value)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.slider.layoutIfNeeded()

        let trackRect = sender.trackRect(forBounds: sender.frame)
        let thumbRect = sender.thumbRect(forBounds: sender.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: sender.value)
        self.milesLabel.center = CGPoint(x: thumbRect.midX, y: sender.frame.origin.y - 55)

        // ** all the other views are aligned with the thumbRect's center as it slides **

        self.clearView.frame.origin = self.milesLabel.frame.origin
    })
    */
}
```

4- Create a new method and insert the code from step-3

```
func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider, value: Float) {

    // round the value for smooth sliding
    sender.value = round(value)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.slider.layoutIfNeeded()

        let trackRect = sender.trackRect(forBounds: sender.frame)
        let thumbRect = sender.thumbRect(forBounds: sender.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: sender.value)
        self.milesLabel.center = CGPoint(x: thumbRect.midX, y: sender.frame.origin.y - 55)

        // ** all the other views are aligned with the thumbRect's center as it slides **

        self.clearView.frame.origin = self.milesLabel.frame.origin
    })
}
```

5- I used the same code that I used for the UIGestureRecognizer but commented out the setValue function and instead used the function from step 4

```
@objc fileprivate func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if slider.isHighlighted { return }

    let point = sender.location(in: slider)
    let percentage = Float(point.x / slider.bounds.size.width)
    let delta = percentage * (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue)
    let value = slider.minimumValue + delta

    // I had to comment this out because the siding was to abrupt
    //slider.setValue(value, animated: true) 

    // ** CALLING THIS FUNCTION FROM STEP-3 IS THE KEY TO GET THE UIView TO CONTROL THE SLIDER **
    sliderValueChanged(slider, value: value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have your mind set on doing it this way, which is okay. But I have a fast alternative for you that might suit your needs.

If you subclass your playback slider and override the `point()` method you can increase the surface area of the slider's thumb.

```
class CustomPlaybackSlider: UISlider {

    // Will increase target surface area for thumb.
    override public func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        var bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
        // Set the inset to a negative value by how much you want the surface area to increase by.
        bounds = bounds.insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -15)
        return bounds.contains(point)
    }

}
```

Might simplify things for you. Although, the only downside of this approach is that the surface area for the touch would extend equally down/up for your dx value and equally left/right for your dy value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be to large. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Too large? You can set the insets however you like. Just change the `dx` and `dy` values in the code above to something smaller (e.g. -5, -10)

Comment: I subclassed UISlider and I’ve been playing with the dx & dy values but no difference. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I found the answer I'm about to post it