# iOS UISlider values mismatched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have implemented Vertical Slider in one of my App which extends `UISlider`. when scrolling is ended/done I am sending commands to the server with the Slider values. Sometimes when I scroll fast up/down and release then slider values are getting mismatched before sending command and after sending command.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   NSLog(@"Value of Slider before sending command=%f",self.value);
   [self sendCommand]; // Here value is something else  
   [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
   NSLog(@"Slider value after sending command=%f",self.value); // Here value changed
}
```

But if I place super call before sending command then everything works fine. Please explain if anyone knows why this is happening.

```
[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
```

More interesting fact is if I don't call super then also everything works well.

Comment: Below link may be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4742966/5184217

Comment: @RajeshDharani I checked link but that seems to be not related what I am looking for. Anyways Thankyou.

Comment: I explained it below . Please check it out.

Comment: @handiansom Please check my reply, I appreciate your answer but unfortunately thats not a case.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the method `[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];` is where the slider updates it's value, based on the interaction. So the value is out of date before super is called.

A call to super should usually be the first line of an overridden method.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just like to confirm why those values are not getting out dated everytime. Even I try synchronize block to make sure another next event don't update values, but that also didn't worked. So I place timer and then call super after some delay will those values will outdated everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the name `touchesEnded:` implies that the slider is done updating, it still might update the value depending on how the user lifted up their finger. This makes sense if you think about a user sliding quickly and then lifting up their finger—they probably expect it to go slightly farther in that direction than their finger actually went.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, from logs it looking same which you are explaining. Because values are being updated. I am looking of some doc. link or more explanation with which I can reproduce it everytime.

Answer (score -1):

> UIKit calls this method when a finger or Apple Pencil is no longer
>   touching the screen. Many UIKit classes override this method and use
>   it to clean up state involved in the handling of the corresponding
>   touch events. The default implementation of this method forwards the
>   message up the responder chain. When creating your own subclasses,
>   call super to forward any events that you do not handle yourself.  For
>   example,  `[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];`
>
> If you override this method without calling super (a common use
>   pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch
>   events, even if your implementations do nothing.

Comment: Than you for your response, yes I read this on apple site. If you will check my question according to it everything is working fine if I remove super call. So that must not be the reason.